# Visualize months in map

Tags: cartography, design, visualisation

I need to visualize in a map the best month to do something in an area.

I've thought of classifying months in 4 groups: (Dec, Jan, Feb // Mar, Apr, May // Jun, Jul, Aug // Sept, Oct, Nov) and displaying them by colors according the season temperature: Blue - cold, red - warm.

The problem that I find with this approach is that it is a global map, and does not make much sense to show January and February with the same color in Australia and Italy.

Any Idea on how I could display global month/season data in a map having in count this?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Perhaps a screen shot of your attribute table is a good start.

Comment: Maybe add [shaded areas](http://www.shadedrelief.com/hypso/hypso.html) to discriminate world's seasons.

Comment: unfortunatly I still have not any data, as is only an idea that I have in mind. Sorry.

Comment: You can think for example in a map showing the best areas for mushroom recollection. Maybe in an area in France there is a polygon which best month is January, I could draw it in blue (cold) but if there is an Area in Australia where you can find the best mushrooms in February, I don't thinka good Idea color it in a cold color.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the statement "visualize in a map the best month to do something" I would start with the following (simple) approach:

Create one map for each month or quarter and start with having two classes in your legend. One is "it's good to do xy" and the other one is "it's bad to do xy". (Of course you can add here more graduated classes and not only the two extreme values) Then color the areas according to their classes, e.g. good with green and bad with red color. So you can see at one glance that activity XY is good/recommended to do in January in Sweden but maybe not in Australia.

If it is mandatory for you to show the temperature on the map, you can do it e.g. by using different colored dots or stripes in the area.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use season names (spring, summer, fall, winter), but you have to reclassify the calendar months given the climate season / hemisphere respectively.
E.g. in Europe, winter could be bound to December, January and February, while in Australia, the winter season is between June and August (or whatever you might choose).

Keep in mind to consider areas near the equator separately, as they have non / minor season variations.